# Delete files once PHP script is completed

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following php file which executes with a cron job. How can I add the functionality that once completed, the xml files in the directory get deleted.

```
<?php 

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","epg");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$dir = "xml-files/";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if (($file !== '.') && ($file !== '..') ) {
    $doc = simplexml_load_file($dir . $file); 

foreach ( $doc->ScheduleData->ChannelPeriod as $channelPeriod )
{
   $channelId = $channelPeriod->ChannelId;

   foreach ( $channelPeriod->Event as $event )
   {
      $beginTime = $event['beginTime'];
      $duration = $event['duration'];
      $programName = $event->EpgProduction->EpgText->Name;
      $description = $event->EpgProduction->EpgText->Description;
      $EventId = $event->EventId;

      $sql = "insert into `epg` (`EventId`,`ChannelId`, `BeginTime`,`Duration`, `ShortName`, `Description`) values ('$EventId','$channelId', '$beginTime','$duration', '$programName', '$description')";

        if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      echo "Database updated successfully";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
      }

   }
}
}
  }
  closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
```

Many thanks for your help guys! much appreciated.

Comment: add at the bottom of your script a call to [unlink()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: use unlink? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your code;

```
function deleteFiles($dir) {
    $files = glob($dir);
    foreach($files as $file){ 
      if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); 
    }
}

deleteFiles("xml-files/*"); This will delete all files under this dir
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

The unlink function deletes a file. If you have more than one file, Loop through the directory and then perform the function for each file.

Answer (score 1):

you use  can `unlink($filename);` function to Delete files once PHP script is completed

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

You can define a shutdown function, whenever the script finishes or exits this function is called:

```
function delete_files() {
    // delete files here
}

register_shutdown_function('delete_files');
```